# my program does not continue compiling if I don't type any letter

Tags: cs50, credit-card

I am solving the problem set1_ credit in cs50. the program woks fine, however  after entering the credit card number, i need to enter any letter in the keyboard in order for the program to give me the answer.
here is my code

```
# include <cs50.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <math.h>


long credit(void);


int main(void)
{
     long long  num = credit();
     long long  num2 = num;
     int c = log10(num), i, sum , sum1, sum2 = 0, digits[c], divid[c], remind[c], total[c], cards[c];
     scanf("%d", &c);
     for ( i = 0; i <= c ; i++)
     {

          digits[c-i] =  num % 10;
          num = num /10;
          scanf("%d", &digits[c-i]);

     }

     if ( c % 2 != 0)

      {
           for ( i = 0 ; i <= c ; i++)
          {

                    if (  i % 2 == 0 )
                    {
                        digits[i] = digits [i] * 2;

                    }

                    else
                    {
                         digits[i] = digits [i];

                    }


          }
      }

      else
      {
           for ( i= 0 ; i <= c ; i++)
           {

                   if ( i % 2 != 0)
                   {
                    digits [i] = digits[i] * 2;

                   }

                   else
                   {
                        digits[i] = digits[i];

                   }


           }
      }

     for (  i = 0; i <= c; i++ )
     {
       remind[i] = digits[i] % 10;
       
     }
     //printf("\n");


     for (i = 0; i <= c; i++)
     {
         divid[i] = digits[i] / 10;
        
     }
     

     for ( i = 0; i <= c; i++ )
     {
           total[i]  = remind[i] + divid[i];
          
     }
      


     for ( i = 0; i <= c ; i++ )
     {
          sum = sum + total[i];

     }
        

 // recreate the card's number in a form of an array

 for ( i = 0; i <= c ; i++)
     {
          cards[c-i] =  num2 % 10;
          num2 = num2 /10;
          scanf("%d", &cards[c-i]);
     }
    
 // check the nature and the validity of a card

      int cards1 = cards[1];
  

 if  (sum % 10 == 0 && cards[0] == 3)
 {
     if (c == 15 )
     {
     switch (cards [1])
     {
         case 4: printf("AMEX");
         break;
         case 7: printf("AMEX");
         break;
     }
     }
     //return 0;
    printf("AMEX");
 }

 else if (cards[0] == 5 && sum % 10 == 0)
 {
     if (c == 16)
     {
     switch (cards [1])
     {
         case 1: printf("MASTERCARD");
         break;
         case 2: printf("MASTERCARD");
         break;
         case 3: printf("MASTERCARD");
         break;
         case 4: printf("MASTERCARD");
         break;
         case 5: printf("MASTERCARD");
         break;
    }
    }
    //return 0;
    printf("MASTERCARD\n");
 }

else if (cards[0] == 4 && sum % 10 == 0)
{
     switch (c)
     {
         case 13: //printf("VISA\n");
          break;
         case 16: //printf("VISA\n");
          break;

     }
      printf("VISA\n");

}

 else
 {
     printf("INVALID\n");
 }
  printf("\n");




}


// get number of digits of an integer

  long  credit(void)
  {
      long long  n;
      do
      {

          n = get_long_long("Number: ");

       }
       while (log10(n)  < 12 || log10(n) > 16);

       return n;
  }
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me solve this issue.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From [man scanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf):

> The **scanf()** function reads input from the standard input stream *stdin*

The program is waiting for keyborad input (*stdin*) at one of the several `scanf` commands.

NB This question description is misleading because the program does compile, it (seemingly) stops *running* until keyboard input.

Comment: do you have any suggestion to prevent type an input in order for the program to continue running

Comment: I didn't study the program and do not understand the purpose of `scanf`. The only input the program needs is the credit card number. At a quick glance the scanf looks unnecessary; a "set" (=) looks sufficient.